# exception vector addresses in u-boot

Tags: linux, exception, memory, u-boot

My platform is iMX28 + u-boot-2013.10 + Linux-3.12.10.

As my understanding, the ARM exception vectors should be loaded in physical address starting from `0x00000000`.  My u-boot image is loaded into `0x40000100` which is in DDR2 memory, and a static RAM of iMX28 is located in address `0x00000000`.

The code in `start.S` is the following:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SYS_DV_NOR_BOOT_CFG
.globl _start
_start:
.globl _NOR_BOOT_CFG
_NOR_BOOT_CFG:
    .word   CONFIG_SYS_DV_NOR_BOOT_CFG
    b   reset
#else
.globl _start
_start:
    b   reset
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
/* No exception handlers in preloader */
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang
    ldr pc, _hang

_hang:
    .word   do_hang
/* pad to 64 byte boundary */
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
    .word   0x12345678
#else
    ldr pc, _undefined_instruction
    ldr pc, _software_interrupt
    ldr pc, _prefetch_abort
    ldr pc, _data_abort
    ldr pc, _not_used
    ldr pc, _irq
    ldr pc, _fiq

_undefined_instruction:
    .word undefined_instruction
_software_interrupt:
    .word software_interrupt
_prefetch_abort:
    .word prefetch_abort
_data_abort:
    .word data_abort
_not_used:
    .word not_used
_irq:
    .word irq
_fiq:
    .word fiq

#endif  /* CONFIG_SPL_BUILD */
    .balignl 16,0xdeadbeef


/*
 *************************************************************************
 *
 * Startup Code (reset vector)
 *
 * do important init only if we don't start from memory!
 * setup Memory and board specific bits prior to relocation.
 * relocate armboot to ram
 * setup stack
 *
 *************************************************************************
 */

.globl _TEXT_BASE
_TEXT_BASE:
#if defined(CONFIG_SPL_BUILD) && defined(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE)
    .word   CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE
#else
    .word   CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE
#endif

/*
 * These are defined in the board-specific linker script.
 * Subtracting _start from them lets the linker put their
 * relative position in the executable instead of leaving
 * them null.
 */
.globl _bss_start_ofs
_bss_start_ofs:
    .word __bss_start - _start

.globl _image_copy_end_ofs
_image_copy_end_ofs:
    .word __image_copy_end - _start

.globl _bss_end_ofs
_bss_end_ofs:
    .word __bss_end - _start

.globl _end_ofs
_end_ofs:
    .word _end - _start

#ifdef CONFIG_USE_IRQ
/* IRQ stack memory (calculated at run-time) */
.globl IRQ_STACK_START
IRQ_STACK_START:
    .word   0x0badc0de

/* IRQ stack memory (calculated at run-time) */
.globl FIQ_STACK_START
FIQ_STACK_START:
    .word 0x0badc0de
#endif

/* IRQ stack memory (calculated at run-time) + 8 bytes */
.globl IRQ_STACK_START_IN
IRQ_STACK_START_IN:
    .word   0x0badc0de

/*
 * the actual reset code
 */

reset:
    /*
     * set the cpu to SVC32 mode
     */
    mrs r0,cpsr
    bic r0,r0,#0x1f
    orr r0,r0,#0xd3
    msr cpsr,r0

    /*
     * we do sys-critical inits only at reboot,
     * not when booting from ram!
     */
#ifndef CONFIG_SKIP_LOWLEVEL_INIT
    bl  cpu_init_crit
#endif

    bl  _main
... ...

/*
 * exception handlers
 */
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
    .align  5
do_hang:
    ldr sp, _TEXT_BASE          /* switch to abort stack */
1:
    bl  1b              /* hang and never return */
#else   /* !CONFIG_SPL_BUILD */
    .align  5
undefined_instruction:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_undefined_instruction

    .align  5
software_interrupt:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_software_interrupt

    .align  5
prefetch_abort:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_prefetch_abort

    .align  5
data_abort:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_data_abort

    .align  5
not_used:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_not_used

#ifdef CONFIG_USE_IRQ

    .align  5
irq:
    get_irq_stack
    irq_save_user_regs
    bl  do_irq
    irq_restore_user_regs

    .align  5
fiq:
    get_fiq_stack
    /* someone ought to write a more effiction fiq_save_user_regs */
    irq_save_user_regs
    bl  do_fiq
    irq_restore_user_regs

#else

    .align  5
irq:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_irq

    .align  5
fiq:
    get_bad_stack
    bad_save_user_regs
    bl  do_fiq

#endif
#endif  /* CONFIG_SPL_BUILD */
```

My questions are

1. the exception handlers are not in desired address 0x00000000, is
   it right?
2. If <1> is right, how to copy these vectors into
   0x00000000? Until now I can not find the code which does copy
   things.
3. If MMU is enabled in u-boot, do the handler become virtual addresses?
4. If <3> is right, is it necessary to convert virtual address into physical address before coping them into 0x00000000?

Thanks!

BR
Cheng Shi

Comment: In order to answer your question we need to know what you wish to do with the knowledge?  Do you just want to know how exception vectors work?  Do you need to change them for some reason? Why?  Is there a problem you're debugging that has lead you to believe you've found a problem here?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I try to add exception handlers in eboot with reference of u-boot. I can not understand how the u-boot implement its exception handlers.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little clearer to understand how we set exception vectors in U-Boot by looking at current as of this writing mainline U-Boot.  For reference that would be this [vectors.S](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/lib/vectors.S;h=49238ed21ed83766fe207c1060cef4e5b2d4257d;hb=HEAD), this [armv7/start.S](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S;h=b18094447b0601e8a7ff539c0b286c693c66d5da;hb=HEAD) and this [u-boot.lds](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/u-boot.lds;h=cfab8b0412344a1f0d7467d461c15d45c162b9fe;hb=HEAD) for the linker script.

With all of this in mind, to answer #1, no, they are not initially at 0x0 but rather where within the image the linker script places them.  They are placed very early physically to make sure they can be easily accessed and copied.  The answer to #2 is that the code by:

```
/* Set vector address in CP15 VBAR register */
```

is what does that.  And then I'm not sure if #3/#4 are really relevant questions anymore as all of this has to take place very early.

Comment: does this apply to x86 as well?

Comment: In so far as you would start by reading the u-boot.lds and start.S files for x86, yes.